# Alt Tab Win32 Message Queue and SetWinEventHook

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, message-queue

I am trying to detect <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> in a Win Event Hook using `SetWinEventHook`. However the callback for the hook is never triggering for <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd>, even though I have a message pump (I am on windows 10)

I came across this idea to process <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> like this when I stumbled across this series of posts:

[Alt Tab overlay Win32 identificator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862213/alt-tab-overlay-win32-identificator)

[SetWinEventHook does not catch any event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931235/setwineventhook-does-not-catch-any-event)

Which describe using a WinEventHook to get the <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> message (which I don't know if it is even efficient or not to use in the modern day). I found an [article by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=683) detailing it (however it doesn't work anymore and I don't know why, but it should.)

How do I get the <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> message in my event callback?

EDIT: Here is my example to mimic what I was doing on a large scale (the small program doesn't work) and to remove doubt from the comments. Here is the entire program plus compile script that shows what I am trying to do but doesn't work at all (what am I doing wrong? the above Raymond Chen Program seems to be effected by it). I am on Windows 10

(Edit, I found EVENT_MIN and EVENT_MAX give me events in the hook, but never the EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART and EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND events)

Compile.bat:

```
@echo off
if not defined DevEnvDir (
    call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
)

if "%Platform%" neq "x64" (
    echo ERROR: Platform is not "x64" - previous bat call failed.
    exit /b 1
)

set FILES=main.cpp

set RELEASEFLAGS=/O2 /DMAINDEBUG=0
set DEBUGFLAGS=/Zi /DMAINDEBUG=1

set LIBS=kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib Winmm.lib

::Release
cl /nologo /W3 /GS- /Gs999999 %RELEASEFLAGS% %FILES% /Fe: AnnoyingSound.exe %LIBS% /link /incremental:no /opt:icf /opt:ref /subsystem:windows

::Debug
cl /nologo /W3 /GS- /Gs999999 %DEBUGFLAGS% %FILES% /FC /Fe: AnnoyingSoundDebug.exe %LIBS% /link /incremental:no /opt:icf /opt:ref /subsystem:console
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
#define STRICT
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HINSTANCE hinst; 
HWND hwndMain; 

LRESULT CALLBACK
WndProc(
    HWND Window,   
    UINT Message,  
    WPARAM WParam, 
    LPARAM LParam) 
{
  if( Message == WM_CLOSE ) 
  {
    PostQuitMessage(0);
  } 
  else
  {
    LRESULT Result  = DefWindowProc( Window, Message, WParam, LParam );
    return Result;
  }
  return 0;
}


HWND g_hwndAltTab = nullptr;
void CALLBACK WinEventProc(
    HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook,
    DWORD event,
    HWND hwnd,
    LONG idObject,
    LONG idChild,
    DWORD dwEventThread,
    DWORD dwmsEventTime
)
{
  printf("Here!\n"); //This never gets called when Alt+Tab pressed
  PCTSTR pszSound = nullptr;
  switch (event) 
  {
    case EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART:
      if (!g_hwndAltTab) 
      {
        g_hwndAltTab = hwnd;
        pszSound = "C:\\Windows\\Media\\Speech On.wav";
      }
      break;
    case EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND:
      if (g_hwndAltTab) 
      {
        g_hwndAltTab = nullptr;
        pszSound = "C:\\Windows\\Media\\Speech Sleep.wav";
      }
      break;
  }
  if (pszSound) {
    PlaySound(pszSound, nullptr, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
  }

}

#if MAINDEBUG
int main()
#else
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hinstPrev,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
#endif
{ 
#if !MAINDEBUG
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine); 
#endif
  { 
    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.style = 0; 
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) WndProc; 
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0; 
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0; 
    wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle( NULL );
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon((HINSTANCE) NULL, 
        IDI_APPLICATION); 
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor((HINSTANCE) NULL, 
        IDC_ARROW); 
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(DKGRAY_BRUSH); 
    wc.lpszMenuName =  "MainMenu"; 
    wc.lpszClassName = "MainWndClass"; 
    
    if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) 
        return FALSE; 
  } 
  hinst = GetModuleHandle( NULL );  // save instance handle 

  HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook = SetWinEventHook(
     EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART, EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND,
     nullptr, WinEventProc, 0, 0,
     WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);

    hwndMain = CreateWindow("MainWndClass", "Sample", 
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, (HWND) NULL, 
        (HMENU) NULL, hinst, (LPVOID) NULL); 
 
    // If the main window cannot be created, terminate 
    // the application. 
 
  if (!hwndMain) 
      return FALSE; 

  if (hWinEventHook)
  {
    ShowWindow(hwndMain, SW_SHOW); 
    UpdateWindow(hwndMain); 
    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ))
    {
      if( msg.message == WM_QUIT ) 
      {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
      } 
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    UnhookWinEvent(hWinEventHook);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

For context of what I am doing:

I am making my own rendering engine in DirectX12, and I am doing all the Win32 stuff manually. One thing I want to do is minimize the window on <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> when in fullscreen. (I heard DirectX renders on top of the window, so that the window is minimized, but DirectX keeps rendering on top of where the window was, so I need to process <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> and then stop the rendering (I don't know if that I true, just saw it in a forum post)). So I need a way of detecting <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> and processing it. (if this doesn't work, I may look into accelerators, but I don't know if that will work with Alt + Tab)

Going through old StackOverflow stuff, I found these two links, but all the examples are either dead or irrelevant:

[Handle Alt Tab in fullscreen OpenGL application properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832041/handle-alt-tab-in-fullscreen-opengl-application-properly)

[Handling minimisation in Fullscreen Win32 OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563596/handling-minimisation-in-fullscreen-win32-opengl)

Comment: many messages not returned from `PeekMessage` but posted direct to windows procedure. you of course never got `WM_KEYUP` or `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_INPUT`, .. without window

Comment: Please read about the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) and verify that this is or isn't.

Comment: @RbMm I did get `WM_INPUT` outside the window though...

Comment: @IInspectable even if it is the XY problem in the long run (which I don't believe it is) for full screen minimization for DirectX. It still would be good to at least have a deeper understanding of the API in use, because the old tutorials are outdated. Even this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972299/best-practices-for-alt-tab-support-in-a-directx-app) has an answer talking about forcing minimization when an alt tab is detected. And the old Raymond Chen article tells me that this is the way to detect Alt+Tab

Comment: You must handle messages inside WindowProc , but not after PeekMessage, because same messages never returned from PeekMessage but direct sent to WindowProc

Comment: @RbMm I updated my example to have the message pump do exactly what you say and it still doesn't work

Comment: Can't you just detect that your window has been minimized? What's significant about knowing it was minimized via Alt+Tab?

Comment: `EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART` and `EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND` generated only if nobody register *ALT+TAB* handler and system default handler (in csrss kernel) post it. but by default *explorer.exe* register self handler and this events not posted. `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` for `ForegroundStaging` class window will be

Comment: It appears that this problem had been around for a while and the way they handled it was to listen on the keys strokes and assume the switch - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588438/the-system-events-event-system-switchstart-and-event-system-switchend-works-in-w